How to prepare HSK level 7-9?
My friend comes from Vietnam.She is learning in China.And she is going to participate in HSK 7-9 examination.She asked me to help her create a mock test of the listening part.I'm a Chinese.But I don't know how to do her a fovor even though I have read the Sample Test.I really want to cope with this problem.Where can I find listening test materials that are suitable for exam difficulty?

To stand any chance in a listening test on this level, you need massive amounts of input, preferably authentic content about a wide variety of topics. You can create listening tests out of anything produced by native speakers for native speakers. If your friend wants to focus on the exam format, the question is not really what listening materials to use, but how to create the questions. This is a different question from the one asked, though.

The HSK7-9 is relatively new, so resources are scant and there's no official "how to prepare" guide currently available.  See the history in my answer to:  What is known about the new HSK 3.0 (2021) format?.
What I know (and I've been tracking it for years now):

The HSK7-9 lists 5636 vocabulary items covering 1200 simplified Chinese characters, as listed in the standards (pdf) (combined with HSK1-6, it's 11093 vocab and 3000 chars); see also: version with watermark removed).  The list is also made available by shawkynasr on Github: vocab 词汇 and chars 汉字 (some characters are duplicate, seemingly because of 多音字, e.g., 谁 is listed under shéi and shuí).
It's likely the student will need to know far more than this (due to 超纲词, extra-curricular words), and this is just the "core" vocab.

There is one exam for HSK7-9, and you get a HSK7, HSK8, or HSK9 certificate based on your performance.  The exam format is described here: HSK（七—九级）考试介绍 (pdf).  Note the exam is incredibly long:



It has a specific format, including listening, reading, writing, translation, and oral.  (Nobody is reporting handwriting tasks, despite it being in previous announcements.)



I translated this over at Chinese Forums.

Chinese teacher Sara Jaaksola took this exam when it first came out (she received the HSK8 certificate).  During this period, she posted two relevant YouTube videos:

HSK 7-9 Mock Exam and how to prepare
Preparing for HSK 7-9 Advanced Exam
HSK 7-9 Advanced Exam - How difficult is it?


YouTuber Laoma Chris took the HSK7-9 exam and posted about it here: I Made Laoma Chris Take The HARDEST Chinese Exam: NEW HSK 9.  He didn't do so well.

The official mock test is available on YouTube here: Q&A Mandarin.

There's only a few published books regarding the HSK7-9:

Grammar Learning Manual (Advanced) 语法学习手册（高等） which I made a YouTube video about here.  This book is for sale here.

Quick Vocabulary Handbook (Levels 7-9 (I) and (II)) 词汇速记速级手册 （上、下册） which I made a YouTube video about here.  They're for sale here and here.

There is an advanced handwriting book (for sale here) but it doesn't seem to be on the exam.




So that's basically all I'm aware of.  My understanding is that almost no students have an actual need to take this exam, so it seems few people are making relevant content.

Go to taobao.com
Enter: hsk7级到9级
Look for books which also have a CD or downloadable audio tracks.
还可以看一看在京东 (jd.com) 或者在你当地的书店!
